# Typescript - mouse click outside div type

Tags: typescript

I need to specify `event` type. Anyone can help with right type exept `any, unknown` ?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const checkIfClickedOutside = (event: any) => {
      if (
        isOpened &&
        selectRef.current &&
        !selectRef.current.contains(event.target)
      ) {
        setIsOpened(false);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
    };
  }, [isOpened]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `MouseEvent`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const checkIfClickedOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      if (
        isOpened &&
        selectRef.current &&
        !selectRef.current.contains(event.target)
      ) {
        setIsOpened(false);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside);
    };
  }, [isOpened]);
```

Do you really need to use `mousedown`?
It looks like you want to close a div, when clicking outside. I would suggest, that you use `click` instead, as it gives the user the ability to cancel their action by performing the `mouseup` outside of the targeted area.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this created error on event.target = "Argument of type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node | null'.
  Type 'EventTarget' is missing the following properties from type 'Node': baseURI, childNodes, firstChild, isConnected, and 43 more"

Comment: I have to add to event.target as HTMLElement to work properly, but it was right way to go.